# A short, clear approach to split a String into letters?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a very basic task in java:

Split a string into letters (of type String, not char).

What I used first was `String.split("123")`, which returned a leading empty space "{,1,2,3}".
Since you need to convert the Array into something else or create a new one to remove the first space - I searched for a good appraoch and found many many variants, but all of them are bulky, like using loops and various conversionos.

So how would you convert a String into a collection of letter Strings?

- by using StringBuffers?
- converting to a ArrayList?
- using split and creating a new Array without leading empty space?
- use Tokenizer?

How does a short, clear approach look like?

My favorite for now is

```
    String[] singleLetters = string.split("");
    singleLetters = Arrays.copyOfRange(singleLetters, 1, singleLetters.length);
```

A better approach is:

```
    String[] singleLetters = string.split("(?!^)")
```

Comment: clarify more: what is a letter? a char or string?

Comment: string split uses regular exression analyisi, which makes them handy, but not very efficient. A loop would be bettet

Comment: A very similar question was asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170551/how-to-using-string-split-in-this-case -- do any of the answers there help you?

Comment: if you are willing to write a loop for every simple thing, you probably dont bother about smelly code?

Comment: agreed with @AlexWien one liner regex are not always effective

Comment: @Skip Since when are loops "smelly code"?

Comment: Its about understandable code, its not about efficiency of code

Comment: @Skip look at the solution you have accepted (regex), and read my comment, this is the smelliest of all solutions. and you probably should study a bit of java introduction, especially in the chapter methods: Using a method you create a solution, such that it is later a one line call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str.split("(?!^)")
```

The regex will prevent the empty string at the beginning from matching, so the result will not contain starting empty string. This solution will work without any assumption.

Comment: the `^` is usually a like start, but what is `?!`

Comment: @Skip: `(?!pattern)` is negative look-ahead (look-behind also work, since `^` is zero-width). I simply check that the current position is not the start of the string, where a split should not occur.

Comment: it is short, works, but the least recommendable solution of all. you trigger a huge regex engine for a primitive task. do not shoot with canons to birds. probably it is the slowest of all solutions, least readable and least maintable. 9 of 10 developpers would not understand whats going on, wasting many dollars / euros thinking, what the hell does this line.

Comment: @AlexWien: You should direct that comment to Skip, since he is the one that it best applies to.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes i have cited this comment above, and i asume that you have understood his question as intelectual demanding task, but you probably would have been solved it otherwise in your projects.

Comment: @AlexWien: Since he takes this out of context, this is the shortest solution for the problem. If there is more context, I might go about it differently.

Comment: @AlexWien Ths is the best solution, since I asked for a short one, not an effective one. Can you disable your "effective thinking" for a moment and read the task?

Comment: @Skip read your own words please: you wanted a "clear" solution. Later you commented that you dont want a smelly solution. now you got a short, but unclear and smelly solution.

Answer (score 2):

why dont you go with [subString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) of lenth 1 - which will give you `String` of individual chars

here is an simple demo code

```
 public void subStrChar{
    String s = "helo";
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){        
        System.out.println(" " + s.substring(i, i+1));
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
public static String[] splitMyString(String input)
  {
  final String[] array = new String[input.length()];
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i)
     array[i] = input.substring(i, i+1);
  return array;
  }
```

Comment: that are 7! lines of code for such a simple thing!!! Isnt there a shorter solution?

Comment: If you use this code , it will take you a single line to use it . Plus , it's very customizeable . Even the built in functions have code behind them , which is usually not that short . Short code doesn't mean that it's the best code you can have. Sometimes, short code does quite a mess behind the scenes .

Comment: here it is about saving my time as a programmer. I don't bother about the code behind the interface. I do not want to write 7 lines of code for such a simple thing every time.

Comment: well you put this code only once , and from this time , you use it by a single , very short line , for example : String[] myArray=splitMyString("Hello @Skip") ;

Comment: @Skip you don't have to write those 7 lines everytime - use method call.
which is hardly of few characters

Comment: So then I would have to create my lib, which I will have to import in every project I am working on? I hope there is a native 1-2 lines approach

Comment: @Skip native 1-2 line approach?? and you think whatever library methods are available `subString()` `split()` etc. have method definition of 1-2 lines

Comment: @Skip , what library ? It's a single function that you can put on any file you wish . You don't have to create a library just for this . You can put it , for example , in a class that its file will be named  "StringsUtil.java"

Comment: Dear Android developer, I am trying to find a general appraoch for this task. This approach I would probably use in many, many projects. So if i can - I will use something from the java core, so that I can do this task fast in any projet. So lets assume I would write an own function. How would I transport it between projects? A general approach would be - creating an own lib, which you would import.

Comment: @Skip there is a unlimit number of simple tasks, where there dors not exist one out of the box one line, efficient solution.  If you need that create your own StringUtil.java class and copy it to each new project. Further i doubt that you really need your question, if you describe the total task, then probably it can be solved otherwise, e.g with String.charAt(i)

Comment: Yes , i agree with AlexWien . Many times you can say about something that it's very basic , but you need to understand that it's impossible to satisfy everybody when you create a programming language. This is not such a long algorithm , and i think that we might even give you a better solution if you wrote why you need it (since i have to say that this question is a little bit weird ) . There are already a lot of functions related to strings . Adding more need a really good justification.

Answer (score 1):

Would `String.toCharArray()` solve your problem?

Comment: nope, then I would have to convert chars to Strings, which needs a loop, which is a pain again

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at guava's [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) maybe.